# How to set the width of the table by settig the first <td> to 100% and the second <td> to a fixed width?

Tags: html, css

I have a table

```
<div class="width1200">
<table>
    <th colspan="2">Title:</th>
    <tr>
    <td>Harry Potter</td>
    <td class="td100">$10</td>
    </tr>
    <th colspan="2">Title:</th>
    <tr>
    <td>Harry Potter</td>
    <td class="td100">$10</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
}

.width1200 {
    width: 1200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.td100 {
    width: 100px;
}
```

I need to make 3 things:

1. The width of the table

- On big screens it should be 1200 px
- The table should be 100% width
- The table should be responsive

2. Width of td

- Second td should always be fixed - 100px
- First td shoul be 100% of the free and responsive

At the moment the table width 100% doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're contradicting yourself. I think you mean to say that on a big screen the table should have a maximum width of 1200px. Right?

```
<style>

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    table-layout: auto;
    width: 100%;
}

td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px;
}

.width1200 {
    max-width: 1200px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.td100 {
    width: 100px;
}

</style>
```

I changed `width: 1200px;` to `max-width: 1200px;` and removed `width: 100%;` from the `td` styling. I did not change the HTML.

I think now it does what you want?

See: [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/yLojt21c/)

Comment: No... At the moment the table has short content and on big sreens its width is less then 500px. And I want it always has width 1200 px on big screens regardless of content

Comment: Yes... That's is exactly what the styles in this answer do. Try them out, but please keep in might that other styles, not visible in your question, can affect the result.

Comment: Yes. You are right. It works if I try it separately. It doesn't work in my project, because it's inside another div: .content {
    grid-area: c;
    justify-self: center;
}
If I remove justify-self: center it works. But how can I center the table now?

Comment: @djangodjames: You have a `<div>` around the table, with the style: `width1200`. You can add something do this style: `margin: auto;`. See: [Center Align Elements](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_align.asp).

Comment: margin: auto makes width less then 500px again )

Comment: @djangodjames It doesn't do it in [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/uwhnzce3/). Sorry, it might be difficult to make that wide enough. I don't think I can help you with this one, I simply don't know what HTML and CSS you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right one:

php code refactored ( wrong markup inside table )

```
<div class="width1200">
  <table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title:</th>
      <th class="td100">Price:</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Harry Potter</td>
      <td class="td100">$10</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Harry Potter</td>
      <td class="td100">$10</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>

  </table>
</div>
```

and new css code:, set width and max width to table and set only to cells with class td100 the specific with

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }

  td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .width1200 {
    max-width: 1200px;
    width:100%;
    padding: 10px;
  }

  .td100 {
    width: 100px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

`table-layout: fixed` allows you to set the widths of columns explicitly. The requirement is that the widths must be set on the `<th>` or `<td>` of the first `<tr>`. The OPs first `<tr>` has `col="2"` making it impossible to set a width for the second column. A workaround:

- is to add another `<tr>` at the top
- add 2 cells `<th>` and/or `<td>`
- do not style any borders to the row
- do not add any content to the new row either
- add `class="td100"` to the 2nd cell of the new hidden row.

BTW each `colspan="2"` isn't in a `<tr>` in OP. They are added in this example.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  table-layout: fixed;/* IMPORTANT */
  width: 100%;
}

td {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 10px;
}

.width1200 {
  width: 1200px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.td100 {
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="width1200">
  <table>
    <tr><!--NEW-->
      <th></th>
      <th class="td100"></th><!--100px column-->
    </tr><!--ROW-->
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Title:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Harry Potter</td>
      <td>$10</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">Title:</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Harry Potter</td>
      <td class="td100">$10</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```